# CoreData predicate for foreign key with NSObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, ios, core-data

I have a relation in Core Data like this:

`A -> B`

and the following tables:

```
A
----
id 
path
ref_foreignkey_B

B
----
id
name
```

The problem is that the foreign key is set as `B` object (inherits from NSObject).

Then I am trying to fetch all entries from A where a reference to a certain B object is set. I know the object B but cannot figure out how to set the `NSPredicate` correctly.

I have tried the following:

```
NSString *complexPredicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ZREF_B == %@", self.B];   
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:complexPredicateFormat];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:filter];
```

... but that results in the following error:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ZREF_B == <B: 0x89d8300> (entity: B; id: 0x89d3ca0 <x-coredata://...`

Does anyone know how to set a `NSManagedObject` (*updated*) as predict filter (represents the where clause)?

**EDIT:
 I am sorry. Of course A and also B inherits from NSManagedObject and NOT NSObject.**

Comment: There is something I don't understand. If B is the class for a entity in Core Data it must inherit from NSManagedObject, not from NSObject.

Comment: @Gabriel Good point! I missed it.

Comment: ZREF_B? Do you try to access the values of the underlying sqlite db directly? Core-Data is no sqlite wrapper! If you want to use stuff like foreign keys you should use sqlite directly. Don't try to force Core-Data to behave like sqlite.

Comment: @Gabriel, yes of course. It inherits from NSManagedObject not NSObject.
@MatthiasBauch: I tried it, yep. But this is why I came here and asked because I thought that this cannot be the solution to, how you have mentioned, directly access the columns. I was looking for something like (pseudocode) `fetch all objects from A that hold a reference to B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **Gabriel** suggestion:

Have you created a Data Model? Why your entities subclass `NSObject`?

Then

If `ref_foreignkey_B` is a relationship for entity `B` you need to use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ref_foreignkey_B == %@", self.B];
```

Obviously if you use that predicate you need to query (use a fetch request) against `A` and not `B`.

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"A"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ref_foreignkey_B == %@", self.B];
```

**Some Notes**

Why do you use `ZREF_B`? This is the column created in the sqlite file (I suppose). You don't have to use that but only properties (attributes or relationships) declared in the data model.

> id, path and ref_foreignkey_B for A
>
> id and name for B

When you deal with Core Data you deal with an **object graph** and not with the db (sqlite for example) itself. This is an important point to understand. You have **not** to deal with the sqlite file (for example) that is created for you. Only with the data model you have created.

In addition, I suggest you to create an inverse relationship from `B` to `A`. This lets you to maintain integrity in the object graph. For info read [Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very strange...
When I have tried this before: `NSString *complexPredicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ref_B == %@", self.B];    
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:complexPredicateFormat];   
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:filter];`
... and geht the aforementioned exception. But when I try it using `[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ref_B == %@", self.B];` it works. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Chris Yes, because the first and the second are different. In the first you create a string with a format and then pass it to the predicate. In the second you create a predicate with a format and use it the request. The second is the right choice.

Comment: @Chris Does it work for you? Upvote too if you find it useful. :)

Comment: Thanks. It is my first time using core data. I thought it must be the same of passing a string directly to the initiator or just by passing a string variable to it... strange. But now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but if "ref_foreignkey_B" is the relationship from A to B then your predicate should look like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetch.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"A" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ref_foreignkey_B == %@", self.B];

NSError *error = nil
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeRequest:fetch];
...
```